# Prove that in $\mathbb{R}$, if $|a-b|>\alpha$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, then outer measure $m^*(A\cup B)=m^*(A)+ m^*(B)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Prove that for sets $A,B$ bounded in $\mathbb{R}$:

If there exists $\alpha > 0$ such that $|a-b|>\alpha$ for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, then outer measure $m^*(A\cup B)=m^*(A)+m^*(B)$.

This comes out of section 2.2 of Royden's Real Analysis.  I'm really having trouble with this one for some reason.  The only theorem that I can see that might be of some help is that outer measure is preserved under set translation.  But I would have to translate each point of one of these sets a different amount, so that seems hopeless.

Because I have so few theorems to work with my hunch is that I need to go back to the very definition of outer measure and do something clever with it, but so far I haven't had any luck.  Can anyone help me?  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HINT: Let $$U=\bigcup_{a\in A}\left(a-\frac{\alpha}2,a+\frac{\alpha}2\right)$$ and $$V=\bigcup_{b\in B}\left(b-\frac{\alpha}2,b+\frac{\alpha}2\right)\;.$$ Suppose that $x\in U\cap V$; then there are $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $$|x-a|,|x-b|<\frac{\alpha}2\;.$$ Is this actually possible?

Comment: I can see it's not, and I feel like your getting at compactness here... I thought about this one all last night though and I still can't figure it out.  You think you could help me out a bit more?

Comment: @IntegrateDisNutsSucka: Not compactness, but simply the fact that $U\cap V=\varnothing$. Thus, $U$ and $V$ are disjoint open sets such that $A\subseteq U$ and $B\subseteq V$. Thus, when you cover $A$ with a countable collection of intervals, you might as well assume that these intervals are contained in $U$, since you’re eventually going to take an infimum anyway. Similarly, the intervals that you use to cover $B$ can be assumed to be contained within $V$. But then the total length of the intervals covering $A\cup B$ is just the sum of the total length of those covering $A$ and the total ...

Comment: ... length of those covering $B$. There are a number of details to sort out when you write it up, but that’s the basic idea.

Comment: Ok ya I kinda went down that path too, but there aren't any theorems about the outer measure of the countable union of disjoint intervals being equal to the sum of there lengths.

Comment: @IntegrateDisNutsSucka: You don’t need such a theorem, since you’re not looking at a countable union of pairwise disjoint intervals. In covering $A\cup B$ you’re looking at a countable family $\mathscr{I}$ of intervals that are generally not disjoint but that can be split into two subfamilies, $\mathscr{A}$ covering $A$ and $\mathscr{B}$ covering $B$, in such a way that each interval in $\mathscr{A}$ is disjoint from each interval in $\mathscr{B}$. Thus, $s(\mathscr{I})=s(\mathscr{A})+s(\mathscr{B})$, where $s(\cdot)$ is the sum of the lengths of the intervals in a given family.

Comment: hmm ok I'll play around with that, thanks.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Looking at your proof, do we not need the condition that A and B are bounded?

Comment: @SallyG: If we allow $m^*$ to take values in the extended reals and define $\infty+r=\infty$ for all extended reals $r$, then we do not need to assume that $A$ and $B$ are bounded.